# Dynamic file system class to automatically create an instance of a specific class (in PHP and PhpStorm)

Tags: php, oop, filesystems, phpstorm

I've created a function that loads a specific class and also should create a new instance of this class:

```
class File {

public static function load($file, $folder = null, $local = false, $classname = null) {
    if ($folder == 'root') {
        $dir = '';
    } elseif ($folder) {
        $dir = $folder . '/';
    } else {
        $dir = 'classes/';
    }
    if ($local) {
        $root = ROOT_ABS;
    } else {
        $root = ROOT_CMS_ABS;
    }
    require_once $root . $dir .  $file . '.php';
    // New Instance
    if ($folder == null || $classname) {
        if (!$classname) {
        return new $file();
        } else {
        return new $classname();
        }
    }
}
```

I've built in some extra parameters to specify if my CMS folder should be accessed (`ROOT_CMS_ABS` AND `ROOT_ABS` constants). So the minimum default case to load a file and also create an object is e.g.:

> $html = File::load('html');

---

**Issue:**

I'm using PhpStorm and usually I could hold <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> to jump to a function of an object.

[image]

But now PhpStorm can't recognize which class has been loaded. In my example this is because I assign `$router` to this class instead of writing `$router = new AltoRouter();`.

---

**Question:**

1) Is there another way that PhpStorm recognized which class I'm referring to?

2) I'm kinda new to OOP in PHP, could I improve my class somehow?

__

Otherwise the function works fine. So this is more likely an IDE issue.

Comment: You can add inline PHPDoc comment with typehint before such assignment, e.g. `/** @var MyClassName $router */`. Otherwise -- using `$router = new AltoRouter();` is much better -- leave class loading for class autoloading mechanism (following PSR-4; be it standard these days  Composer .. or your own implementation)

Comment: Thank you, would accept that as answer if it'd be one. @LazyOne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily solve it by adding inline PHPDoc comment with type hint before such assignment. For example:

```
/** @var MyClassName $router */
$router = File::load('AltoRouter', 'route');
```

---

Other than that: using `$router = new AltoRouter();` is much better -- leave actual class loading for class autoloading mechanism (following PSR-4; be it standard these days Composer .. or your own implementation).